# Rotary encoder is giving less PPR reading

Tags: pi-2, rpi.gpio, arduino, c, wiringpi

I am testing 400 PPR(Pulses Per Revolution) rotary encoder using code.I am rotating it by using the hand. I have connected Phase A and Phase B and also, ground and Vcc properly. The code is giving less than 400 counts in every rotation.eg. sometimes 385,350,360,390. Maximum time the range is in between 350 to 400. The code is given below:

```
#define PIN1 14
#define PIN2 10

volatile long pos;

volatile uint8_t state;

void pin_isr(void) 
{
    uint8_t p1val = digitalRead(PIN1);

    uint8_t p2val = digitalRead(PIN2);

    uint8_t s = state & 3;

    if (p1val) s |= 4;
    if (p2val) s |= 8;
    state = (s >> 2);

    switch (s) {
        case 1: case 7: case 8: case 14:
            pos++;
            return;
        case 2: case 4: case 11: case 13:
            pos--;
            return;
        case 3: case 12:
            pos += 2;
            return;
        case 6: case 9:
            pos -= 2;
            return;
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // sets up the wiringPi library
    if (wiringPiSetup() < 0) {
        perror("wiringPiSetup");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   
    pinMode (PIN1,  INPUT) ;
    pinMode (PIN2,  INPUT) ;
    pullUpDnControl(PIN1, PUD_UP);
    pullUpDnControl(PIN2, PUD_UP); 
    if ( wiringPiISR (PIN1, INT_EDGE_BOTH, &pin_isr) < 0 ) {
        perror("wiringPiISR");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( wiringPiISR (PIN2, INT_EDGE_BOTH, &pin_isr) < 0 ) {
        perror("wiringPiISR");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Show position every second
    while ( 1 ) {
        printf( "%ld\n", pos);
        delay( 10 ); // wait 1 second
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I have written similar code for Arduino which perfectly working fine. Every time I am getting exactly 400 counts per rotation. Does anyone know what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given enough details.  The most important factor is the frequency of pulses.  Is that 400 pulses an hour, a minute, a second, a millisecond?

I am going to assume the pulses are too frequent and the Linux interrupt system can not keep up.

Try one of the following examples to see if you get the same problem.

C: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#C_rotary_encoder_c

C + pigpio daemon: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_RED

Python + pigpio daemon: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py

Comment: I have mention PPR (Pulses per revolution). I am rotating the encoder by using the hand.So, whenever I am rotating it I am getting pulses less than 400 in one revolution

Comment: @Ashish Are you doing one rotation an hour, a minute, a second, a millisecond?

Comment: maybe you have misunderstood the operation of the encoder. Encoder gives the pulses when we revolve (its shaft) it by using external force.Here is the link of the  encoder which I am using:  https://robu.in/run-rotary-encoder-arduino-code/

Comment: Also, i am using wiring pi library and revolution of the encoder to complete the one rotation is taking at least one second.

Comment: @Ashish You need to try one of the examples I gave.  Your code will not magically start working.

Comment: thank you @joan I will definitely try. But before this, I was using wiring pi library. can I use same GPIO pine declaration here?How to use this library?

Comment: Hi @joan thanks, its working fine and I am getting the proper  pulse. The only question I have is I am using wiring pi library, can I use both libraries in the same project. For other sensor and motor control I am using wiring pi now what should I do.Or can you please tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: If the code works on the Arduino, and you have correctly copied it to the Pi, that suggests the algorithm is okay.  I'm assuming you are making roughly one turn per second, which will result in 400*4 or 1600 GPIO state changes (4 per encoder position).  You are checking the GPIO level in the ISR.  The ISR will be called 50µs+ after the GPIO level change.  It may well have changed again by the time you test it in the ISR thus giving incorrect results.

Comment: Linux is a multi-user, multi-tasking operating system.  Arduino is single-user, single-tasking.  pigpio works differently and you get told the level at the time of the ISR.  pigpio and wiringPi can coexist quite happily.  pigpio can probably control motors and sensors as well as if not better than wiringPi.

Comment: HI, @joan I have one single question regarding this example that is why I am not asking a new question. If I want to create two encoders at the same time which changes I have to make?How can I use this   re_decoder dec(7, 8, callback); function again?

Comment: @Ashish From memory you just create another class and instantiate with either the same GPIO (if for some reason you want to read a single encoder twice) or from the GPIO connected to the new encoder.